# Android Programming rectangle animation (height) & by click stop animation

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a rectangle in the middle of the screen (bottom). When I start the app the rectangle should grow (max height = screen height). And if I tap on the screen (random position) the animation should stop and the height should stay. How can I do something like this? Can anyone give me some keywords or links?

Now I started with the rectangle an the animation. My first question should I place the rectangle into a `ImageView`? I want to get the position from the rectangle when I tapped the screen.

Here is the `activity_main.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nocompany.gamefirsttry.main_activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`@drawable/rectangle.xml`

```html
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:endColor="#000"/>

    <size
        android:height="100px"
        android:width="50px"/>
</shape>
```

`@anim/rectangle_anim.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="15.0" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

`main_activity.java`

```html
package nocompany.gamefirsttry;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class main_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView rectangle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rectangle);
        Animation recSize = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rectangle_anim);
        rectangle.startAnimation(recSize);
    }
}
```

I hope you understood my question and give me some tips/hints or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do for this is create your own view. Then within the view draw the rectangle and animate it with a thread. Changing its onDraw with the time. Then you can catch the onTouch as well to stop it appropriately. You could totally animate such things with an animator if you wanted to, but you are still left with drawing a changing rectangle (which animator can do) but then the stopping would still require you listen for touches on the view. You might be able to do all of this with an imagebutton. Then do the one touch event to stop the animator, but it all seems to call out for a custom view.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Now I have some points where I can looking for! Thanks